# How do electron acceptors and donors affect molecular geometry?

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecules, matter

I'm currently working with two molecules: Ethylene $CH_2CH_2$ and $CH_2CHCH_2$ (whose name I don't know).
The question is how does doping them with an electron acceptor/donor affect their geometry?

My initial instinct would be to say that by giving away their electrons, donors would allow the creation of an unlinked pair of electrons which would tranform the geometry around the carbon atoms from triangular to (imperfect) tetrahydral, but I'm guessing, and I don't know what an acceptor would do.
I would very much appreciate the opportunity to understand the logic behind the answer too, if possible.
Thank you!

Comment: Your second compound is wrong: look at the middle carbon.

Comment: Look up “propene” in wikipedia or anything pertaining to elementary organic chemistry.

Comment: Study Lewis acids: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Acids_and_Bases/Acid/Lewis_Concept_of_Acids_and_Bases